# Delegating method to has_many association ignores preloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to delegate a method to a `has_many` association in rails, AND still save the preloaded data on that association, all while following the law of demeter?  Currently it seems to me that you are forced to choose one or the other. That is: keep your preloaded data by NOT delegating, or lose your preloaded data and delegate.

Example: I have the following two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs

  delegate :all_have_title?, to: :blogs, prefix: false, allow_nil: false

  def all_blogs_have_title?
    blogs.all? {|blog| blog.title.present?}
  end
end


class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def self.all_have_title?
    all.all? {|blog| blog.title.present?}
  end
end
```

Notice: that `User#all_blogs_have_title?` does the exact same thing as the delegation method of `all_have_title?`.

The following, as I understand it, violates law of demeter.  However: it maintains your preloaded data:

```
user = User.includes(:blogs).first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Blog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."user_id" = 1
  => #<User id: 1, name: "all yes", created_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00", updated_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00">

user.all_blogs_have_title?
 => true
```

Notice: when I called  `user.all_blogs_have_title?` it DID NOT do an additional query.  However, notice that the method `all_blogs_have_title?` is asking about `Blog` attributes, which is violating law of demeter.

Other way which applies law of demeter but you lose the preloaded data:

```
user = User.includes(:blogs).first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Blog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."user_id" = 1
  => #<User id: 1, name: "all yes", created_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00", updated_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00">

user.all_have_title?
  Blog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  => true
```

Hopefully the downside of both implementations is apparent. Ideally: I would like to do it the second way with the delegate implementation, but to maintain that preloaded data.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Explanation**

The reason why `all_have_title?` delegation doesn't work properly in your example is that your are delegating the method to `blogs` association, but yet defining it as a `Blog` class method, which are different entities and thus receivers.

At this point everybody following would be asking a question why there is no `NoMethodError` exception raised when calling `user.all_have_title?` in the second example provided by OP. The reason behind this is elaborated in the [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) documentation (which is the resulting object class of the `user.blogs` call), which rephrasing due to our example namings states:

> that the association proxy in `user.blogs` has the object in `user` as `@owner`, the collection of his `blogs` as `@target`, and the `@reflection` object represents a `:has_many` macro.
>   This class delegates unknown methods to `@target` via `method_missing`.

So the order of things that are happening is as follows:

1. `delegate` defines `all_have_title?` instance method in `has_many` scope in `User` model on initialization;
2. when called on `user` `all_have_title?` method is delegated to the `has_many` association;
3. as there is no such method defined there it is delegated to `Blog` class `all_have_title?` method via `method_missing`;
4. [`all`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all) method is  called on `Blog` with `current_scope` which holds `user_id` condition (`scoped_attributes` at this point is holding `{"user_id"=>1}` value), so there is no information about preloading, because basically what is happening is:

   ```
   Blog.where(user_id: 1)
   ```

   for each `user` separately, which is the key difference in comparison with the preloading that was performed before, which queries associated records by multiple values using `in`, but the one performed here queries a single record with `=` (this is the reason why the query itself is not even cached between these two calls).

**Solution**

To both encapsulate the method explicitly and mark it as a relation-based (between `User` and `Blog`) you should define and describe it's logic in the `has_many` association scope:

```
class User
  delegate :all_have_title?, to: :blogs, prefix: false, allow_nil: false

  has_many :blogs do
    def all_have_title?
      all? { |blog| blog.title.present? }
    end
  end
end
```

Thus the calling you do should result in the following 2 queries only:

```
user = User.includes(:blogs).first
=> #<User:0x00007f9ace1067e0
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Blog Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `blogs`.* FROM `blogs` WHERE `blogs`.`user_id` IN (1)
user.all_have_title?
=> true
```

this way `User` doesn't implicitly operate with `Blog`'s attributes and you don't lose you preloaded data. If you don't want association methods operating with `title` attribute directly (block in the `all` method ), you can define an instance method in `Blog` model and define all the logic there:

```
class Blog
  def has_title?
    title.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that follows law of demeter AND honors the preloaded data (doesn't hit the database all over again).  It is certainly a bit odd, but I could not find any other solution, and I really want to know what others think about this:

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord     
  has_many :blogs

  def all_blogs_have_title?
    blogs.all_have_title_present?(self)
  end
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def self.all_have_title_present?(user)
    user.blogs.any? && user.blogs.all? {|blog| blog.title.present?}
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
user = User.includes(:blogs).first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Blog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."user_id" = 1
  => #<User id: 1, name: "all yes", created_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00", updated_at: "2017-12-05 20:28:00"> 

user.all_blogs_have_title?
=> true
```

So we notice that it is not hitting the database again (honoring the preloaded data), and instead of the `user` reaching into the attributes of it's neighbor (`Blog`), it delegates the question to it's neighbor and allows the neighbor (again: `Blog`) to answer questions about *it's own attributes*.

The odd thing is clearly inside the `Blog` model where the class method asks `user.blogs`, so `Blog` knows about the association on `User`.  But perhaps this is ok because, after all, `Blog` and `User` share an association with each other.

Answer (score 0):

This  [scope_delegation gem](https://github.com/foraker/scope_delegation) will do your work.

if you will define your work like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :blogs

   delegate :all_have_title?, to: :blogs, prefix: false, allow_nil: false
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def self.all_have_title?
    where.not(title: nil)
  end
end
```

This should work :)